# Find descriptions that have 'taxes' as 2nd word

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a statement that will output all of the descriptions that have taxes as the 2nd word. I am fairly confident with the first 4 lines but after that I am confused on how to do this. What I am will execute without error but it displays no information. Based on the information in my tables, there should be 7 things being displayed

```
SELECT vendor_name, account_description
FROM ap_vendors v
  JOIN ap_general_ledger_accounts la
    ON v.default_account_number = la.account_number
WHERE SUBSTR(LOWER(account_description),INSTR(account_description, ' ')) = 'taxes';
```

Comment: When you say second word, do you need to account for punctuation, spaces, etc?  If the second "word" is `taxeseseses` then is that a match or not?  How robust do you need this to be?  Do you have examples of the cases you need to cater for?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only work if 'taxes' is always the second and the last word. 
If there are more words after taxes, it will not work.

Try Adding +1 to the 4th line.

WHERE SUBSTR(LOWER(account_description),INSTR(account_description, ' ')+1) = 'taxes';

Answer (score 0):

How about using `LIKE`:

```
WHERE account_description LIKE '% taxes%' AND
      account_description NOT LIKE '% % taxes'
```

If your database supports regular expressions, you can use those as well.